# How to make tableView Scroll Automatically to top/bottom?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, scroll

This is just a test, which i might add it to the app. Well.... I have a `tableView`.

1. If click `button1`,  I want the tableView to scroll up automatically to the top.
2. If I click `button2` I want the tableView to scroll down automatically to the bottom.

How can this be done ? What about Scroll Speed ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can also look at the scroll view's `setContentOffset:animated:` method.

Going to the top would mean,

```
[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];
```

and the bottom would be,

```
CGFloat height = self.tableView.contentSize.height - self.tableView.bounds.size.height;
[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, height) animated:YES];
```

You won't have control over the animation duration.

The only problem with `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:` is that it might not be helpful when section and table headers are set.

Comment: "Deepak" - always provides the best possible answer for any situation. Thanks man.

Comment: What is the best way for one to compensate for contentInset on a table view?

Answer (score 1):

[scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/scrollToRowAtIndexPath%3aatScrollPosition%3aanimated%3a)

Scrolls the receiver until a row identified by index path is at a particular location on the screen.

```
- (void)scrollToRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath atScrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition animated:(BOOL)animated
```